# Falla en conexion con BD desde sts Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

buenas tardes comunidad estoy iniciando una aplicacons web Rest con spring JPA e intentando conectar con MySQL como motor de BD, pero por mas que lo intento tengo un inconveniente que no me permite levantar el back por alguna falla en la conexion con la BD

tengo estas clases y configuraciones

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.inmobiliaria</groupId>
    <artifactId>inmobiliaria</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>inmobiliaria</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

aplication.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_estates?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=America/Bogota
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

y cree una entidad para pruebas

```
`
package com.inmobiliaria.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="estates")
@Data
public class Estates {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    
    private String address;
    private String description;
    private String type;
    private int stratum;
    private int parking;
    private int bedrooms;
    private int bathrooms;
    private float price;
    private float size;
}
`
```

agradesco si me pueden ayudar ya que siempre que intento levantar el servidor local del sts me genera este error

[2m2023-09-01T16:35:13.501-05:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m19636[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
[2m2023-09-01T16:35:13.505-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19636[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-09-01T16:35:13.530-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19636[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger[0;39m [2m:[0;39m

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-09-01T16:35:13.558-05:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m19636[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

intente actualizar librerias y dependecias, borrar temportales de mi pc

Comment: No parece haber errores en tu código, y no quiero decir que no tienes la dependencia "mysql-connector-j" ya que está en el pom.xml; sin embargo, recibo el mismo error cuando agrego la dependencia pero no sincronizo los cambios. Esto hace que aparentemente la dependencia esté en el pom y el JAR sea traído, pero no se actualizan los cambios en el clashpath. No estoy utilizando STS, pero el error parece ser el mismo.

Comment: hola estimado y lograste resolverlo de alguna forma no se instalar la libreria de hirraki directamente ?

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice:

**Failed to determine a suitable driver class**

Osea que anda fallando el driver, y esto es porque en las versiones actuales de mysql el driver es ahora asi:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Ya con ese cambio tu datasource quedaria asi:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Si mi respuesta te ayuda dame flecha arriba :D

Comment: Hola estimado gracias, pero no funciono ya realice la modificacion y el error persiste, parece que fuera un error de las librerias porpias de spring :(

Comment: Te arroja el mismo error o que dice?